# dense subgroup in pro v topology

Tags: profinite-groups

Let $V$ be a extension closed pseudovariety. The pro-$V$ topology on a group $G$ is the unique group topology such that the set of normal subgroups $N$ with $G/N$ in $V$ is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of the identity.
Let $K$ be a finitely generated subgroup of finite index of free group $FG(A)$  which is dense respect to pro-$V$ topology on the free group. Is it true that $K$ contains a subgroup of rank n(=rank of free group) which is $V$-dense?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, this fails trvially for the profinite topology, since any subgroup of finite index is closed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write $K$ is finitely generated subgroup. So in profinite topology this is true.

Comment: Ah right, I misunderstood you. Yes, it is true in the pro finite topology.

Comment: Also this true in pro p topology when p is a prime number. But I do not know for other extension closed pseudovariety